# Code freezing when dealing with multiple singleton classes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two singleton classes. I have implemented the code in Playground. Code is as below

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
class A {
    private init() {
        print("1")
        setB()
        print("2")
    }

    static let a = A()

    func setB() {
        _ = B.b
    }
}

class B {
    private init() {
        setA()
    }

    static let b = B()

    func setA() {
        print("3")
        _ = A.a // Doesn't execute beyond this
        print("4")
    }
}

_ = A.a
```

I am creating `Class A` object outside, which in turn creates object of `Class B`. Since `A` is singleton, object is already created. Then inside constructor of `B` i am accessing the object of `A`. But code doesn't execute beyond that line. Output of the above code is

```
1
3
```

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with the code? I want to know why it stops executing. There are no syntax errors/warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since A is singleton, object is already created.

Not correct. Static properties are lazy per default. This means that neither `A.a` not `B.b` will be instantiated until they are first used. This is just a detail though, as any attempt to initialize `A.a` will lead to attempting to re-access the static property before its initialization has completed (leading, most likely, to a threading deadlock).

When you invoke `_ = A.a` you will start a call-chain that ends in an attempt to get a reference of `A.a` before it has finished its initialization.

```
// instantiate A.a
_ = A.a

// -> calls init() of A
// -> calls setB() of A
// -> instantiates B.b
// -> calls init() of B
// -> calls setA() of B
// -> tries to grab a reference to A.a, but the
//    initialization of A.a has not yet finished!
//    (as you can see by the lack of printing "2").
```

I don't exactly know what this would imply (undefined behavior?), but possibly, since initialization of `A.a` is yet to finish, the access of `A.a` in `setA()` of `B` will believe it is time to instantiate `A.a`, re-starting the call-chain that ends, again, with an attempt to access `A.a` before it has been initialized; leading to a recursive call-chain loop (which will "freeze" and eventually crash the playground).

Another probably more plausible scenario, as pointed out my @MartinR below, is that we don't actually enter a recursive call-chain but rather a threading deadlock (due to the thread-safety of static properties), as soon as we try to access `A.a` before it has been fully initialized.

In any case, the core issue is attempting to access `A.a` before it has fully completed its initialization.

Comment: My guess would be a threading deadlock: Static properties are thread-safe, but `A.a` is not fully initialized when `_ = A.a` is executed in `setB() -> setA()`

Comment: @MartinR yeah that sounds more plausible than repeated attempts to initialize it (attempts that never fully finishes). Thanks!